# How to do validation before postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, postback

I have custom control with ASP.Net validators.

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, "javascript:return DoSmth();");

function DoSmth() {
var cBox = confirm("Are you sure?");
if (!cBox) {
    return false;
}
else {
//Invoke validation
}
```

When I push button submit, I call confirm box. If I press cancel - all right. But if I press ok, I need to do validation. How can I stop postback and do valiadation?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do client side validation with javascript.

Comment: `javascript:` does not beling into event handlers. They always use JavaScript. Actually, it only works because it defines a label.. if JavaScript didn't have labels it would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Call client-side `Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup)`. It returns `true` if the page was valid.

```
function DoSmth() {
    var cBox = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (!cBox) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
    }
}
```

**EDIT(an answer to a comment):**

`validationGroup` here is a string variable, and it is not necessary to pass it to `DoSmth` function (honestly, the answer should be: *it depends*).

If this function is defined in a `.js` file, then yes, `validationGroup` should be passed as an argument.

If it is a part of the page/control it would be easier to use e.g. server side constructions here:

```
return Page_ClientValidate('<%= btnSubmit.ValidationGroup %>');
```

where `btnSubmit` is a button which causes validation, or use just a string variable.

Comment: And in this case you should pass validationgroup to DoSmth method in your custom control AddAttributes code.

Comment: @gbs, added explanation to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can stop a postback with ASP.Net Validation.  From MSDN:

> "Validation occurs after page
>   initialization (that is, after view
>   state and postback data have been
>   processed) but before any change or
>   click event handlers are called. "

I use [jQuery Validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) and then check the value in the same method as the confirm dialog.

```
function DoSmth() {

$('#form1').validate({
                rules: { field: "required" }
            });


var cBox = confirm("Are you shure?");
if (cBox && $('#form1').valid() ) {
    //form is valid 
}
else {
   return false;
}
```